# Curl stopped working all of a sudden

Tags: php, curl

I was working on a project for which i was using curl to fetch some data from a website (more so like a API call). Two nights ago I checked everything and it was working smoothly but all of a sudden yesterday morning I started getting an error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Empty string supplied as input

Filename: controllers/user.php

My code is:

```
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$data=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($data);
$doc->save("test2.xml");
```

The url is correct as the everything was working 2 days ago!

I am working on wamp server currently and php_curl is enabled!

This is the [API](http://wiki.nus.edu.sg/display/ivlelapi/Module) i am trying to call! Is there any other method to send the request and fetch the data apart from curl?

Comment: What changed on your server?  Are you on a shared hosting system?  Maybe they performed maintenance and changed a library or configuration setting...check `phpinfo()` for anything that looks different.

Comment: More likely is something about the website fetched has changed. What kinds of headers does it return?

Comment: I am testing on localhost so nothing has changed!

Comment: Nothing has changed with the website. I just rechecked their API, the URI template is the same. It is a GET method with respone type XML.

Comment: Saurabh: Something has changed for sure. If nothing had changed, it would still be working. What's the URL?

Comment: Does the API you are connecting to always return something?  It seems like you just need to do a check for empty data being returned.

Comment: It does return something everytime. This is a competition i am working on and I have checked their forum, no one has complained about such a thing happening with them. Moreover i also emailed them and they said that the API is working correctly

Comment: Is there an alternative to curl which i can try just to be sure?

Comment: I have edited my post to include the API i am trying to make calls to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternate try `echo file_get_contents($url);`

Also see what you get if you do something like this:

```
$data=curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
echo "<br>";
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);
curl_close($ch);
```

The curl info and curl error might give you some insight about the request.

Comment: Message: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Comment: This is the [API](http://wiki.nus.edu.sg/display/ivlelapi/Module) i am trying to call! Is there any other method to send the request and fetch the data apart from curl?

Comment: I enabled openSSL and i now have the https wrapper but now i get a 'failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request' error!

Comment: @Saurabh .. curl is easier method to get the data, otherwise you will need to work with basic file functions like fsockopen. Try a different https URL, just to make sure that everything is working ok ( which seems like it is after u enabled open ssl ) , if thats the case then you need to check the URL and the parameters that it needs to form the request the web server is expecting